# Javascript requirejs in development but compiled in production

Tags: javascript, requirejs, modularity

I'm beginning to evaluate javascript module tools like RequireJS for javascript modularization. This seems useful, especially during development, so I don't need to recompile all of the js files into `mylib-<version>.js` whenever I change one of the dependent files.

My app is distributed with both html and javascript files, and in production, I would like to use the compiled version of the javascript file.

So in development, my html file might look something like

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

But in production, I would expect it to look more like

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="mylib-1.0.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

I wouldn't think it production that there should be any need to reference requirejs if I am distributing a compiled file.

Is there a way to do this without having to manually change my html files before I distribute the app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RequireJs has an [optimization tool](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html), which can help you to minify and concatenate your modules. It has a lot of options, and can be difficult to use, but it gets easier with a build tool like [GruntJs](http://gruntjs.com/) or (especially) [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), which uses GruntJs to build.

In both you can use the `rjs` task (which optimizes modules), but again **Yeoman** is a bit easier since it has generators which will configure it already for you:

```
// usemin handler should point to the file containing
// the usemin blocks to be parsed
'usemin-handler': {
  html: 'index.html'
},
// rjs configuration. You don't necessarily need to specify the typical
// `path` configuration, the rjs task will parse these values from your
// main module, using http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#mainConfigFile
//
// name / out / mainConfig file should be used. You can let it blank if
// you're using usemin-handler to parse rjs config from markup (default
// setup)
rjs: {
  // no minification, is done by the min task
  optimize: 'none',
  baseUrl: './scripts',
  wrap: true,
  name: 'main'
},
```

In the `index.html` you just use a comment line to specify which js files should be minified/concatenated to which output file:

```
    <!-- build:js scripts/amd-app.js -->
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/vendor/require.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

In the example above, the modules will be concatenated to ONE file, named `amd-app.js`.

**Edit:**

This will be done by executing `grunt` from the command line. This will start a lot of useful tasks, which will build the project in a `dist` folder, but again this is highly adaptable.

The resulting `index.html` file (in `dist`) has only (if you want) one javascript file:

```
<script src="scripts/15964141.amd-app.js"></script>
```

**My advice: use Yeoman to make life easier (at least for handling minification/concatenation).**

Comment: If I distribute index.html with my app, it will still have a dependency on scripts/vendor/require.js though, is that correct?

Comment: No, this is the source. When Yeoman builds, it copies all to an destination folder (dist in this case). See edit

Comment: Oh I see, so it compiles the html files as well?

Comment: It does lots of things: optimizes image files, compiles coffeescript to javascript, compiles compass to css, minification, makes a cache manifest, ...

Comment: A feature of grunt/yeoman. You have to see it as a bundle of useful tasks (where rjs is one of them, which is the requirejs optimizer).

Comment: Thanks, I've only used grunt for minimal things, good to know about this.

Comment: @asgoth , would you mind updating this answer with the latest since a lot of the Grunt / Yeoman environment has changed since you wrote this.  Thanks for the answer even if you can't update it :)

Comment: Yeoman is NOT an extension of Grunt. That's just plain misleading. It is a different tool with different purpose.

Comment: @Petri: A lot has changed to Yeoman since I've posted this answer (which i didnt follow closely due to other projects). I'll remove the misleading reference.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to compile your depency tree into one file using the [r compiler](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#onejs). After that you can a striped down AMD loader like [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond). At least you have to find a way to change the url in your index html.

Take a look at [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) which can automatize the whole thing, there a bunch task to like [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) that helps you with the process.