# r.js requireJS. Must I modify my HTML?

Tags: requirejs, r.js

Using requireJS to load 4 JS files, my HTML markup looks like this :

```
<script data-main="js/app" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>
```

I run r.js to compile files to main-built.js.

How can I now ask requireJS to load main-built.js instead of all the js files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use server-side code to determine the environment and load the appropriate optimized script or use a tool like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/). Have a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325554/javascript-requirejs-in-development-but-compiled-in-production).